# Instagram min_tag_id stoppes working

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I've been using Instagram's `min_tag_id` for a while now without any major problems. Recently I realized that I stopped getting new content after a while.

For example when looking for `tags/chicken/media/recent` the first time, I get a bunch of posts and a `min_tag_id` like `AQC8xyA5c5TTZycztD0Y3pb5ECQ7BbDUN-UPvGeN_ki-rroC3YbV4UH9Hr44UK4cAaKfRb5e1hWCyYqECiMiwG2XUnP5-6-F8MW7jCPSMZIgVqbPn9_HIZyhtOT3isPopSU`.

I store this `min_tag_id` in a database and use it few seconds later to  make a new request to the API - to get new content.

But somehow, after some time, Instagram won't deliver me new content  anymore.

Then I have to delete the last `min_tag_id` and make a new request without it. Instagram will of course respond with a bunch of posts I already know, but also with a new `min_tag_id` which will work again for some time.

I cannot reproduce the problem just yet, it just happens. Sometimes it takes a few hours, sometimes it seems to be a few days.

Does anyone know why this is happening or even have a solution that does not include deleting the old `min_tag_id` sporadically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error I made. I only stored the `min_tag_id` when there was content delivered by Instagram. But when there where no new posts, I considered the request as *"not successful"* and didn't care to store the new `min_tag_id`.

Instagram sends a freshly generated `min_tag_id` for every request, regardless if there is new content or not. One always has to use the new `min_tag_id`, even though the *"old"* id still works for a while. Apparently the *"old"* `min_tag_id` will expire at some point.